# Transform JSON into excel table using PowerQuery

Tags: json, parsing, export-to-csv, powerquery

I have a JSON data file with this structure:

```
{

   "31b5c99bb7d0f55394ca9a2e8e386e4dd154cf1e33cf5bee4fd6b2dc8092550d":{

      "result":{

         "final_action":"warn",

         "header":[

            "Image_Id",

            "Repo_Tag",

            "Trigger_Id",

            "Gate",

            "Trigger",

            "Check_Output",

            "Gate_Action",

            "Whitelisted",

            "Policy_Id"

         ],

         "row_count":24,

         "rows":[

            [

               "31b5c99bb7d0f55394ca9a2e8e386e4dd154cf1e33cf5bee4fd6b2dc8092550d",

               "redacted",

               "41cb7cdf04850e33a11f80c42bf660b3",

               "dockerfile",

               "instruction",

               "Dockerfile directive 'HEALTHCHECK' not found, matching condition 'not_exists' check",

               "warn",

               false,

               "48e6f7d6-1765-11e8-b5f9-8b6f228548b6"

            ],
```

Im trying to transform it into a table using excel PowerQuery but not sure how to use header list as columns and then fill the rows wih the content of each "row" list. So far I was able to convert the header into columns only, and since in each row field there is a list of 9 more items every time i try to turn them into rows it fails.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I removed the images and add more details of my issue.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a List of Records with the column headers being the field names, and the Row information being the field values.
- convert to a table:

```
let

//Read in the json document
    Source = Json.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\ron\Desktop\new 3.json")),

//convert to a table and expand the record columns
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source),
    #"Expanded Value" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Value", {"result"}, {"result"}),
    #"Expanded result" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Value", "result", {"header", "rows"}, {"header", "rows"}),
    #"Expanded rows" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded result", "rows"),

//create list of records from the JSON
// This code may be slightly different if you have multiple rows
    #"Records" = {Record.FromList(List.Combine(#"Expanded rows"[rows]), List.Combine(#"Expanded rows"[header]))},

//convert those records to a table
    #"New Table" = Table.FromRecords(#"Records"),

//set the data types (optional)
    #"Type Data" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"New Table", {{"Whitelisted", type logical}} & 
        List.Transform(List.RemoveMatchingItems(Table.ColumnNames(#"New Table"),{"Whitelisted"}), each {_, type text}))
in
    #"Type Data"
```

[image]